# Unity crashes after reverting back-up of project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to implement ads in my game using ironSource, but before implementing i back-upped my project in my Downloads folder, after a lot of tinkering i set-up the Unity side of things, but had problems on the ironSource site. So i ended up scrapping ads all together, closed unity fully and switched the 2 project folders around, so i had the pre-ad implemented project. Since then the Unity editor keeps crashing somewhere between 1-60 seconds when in play mode.

I tried renaming my Library folder to Library_temp and letting Unity re-import everything, i also tried regenerating the .csproj files, but that did nothing. So now i practically can't test my game, and even if i do it's for a very limited time which is annoying to work with.

Comment: How about a git bisect to try understand when that happened?

Comment: If the editor crashes in runtime, you probably have a problem with your runtime scripts.